# CakePHP set image in javascript (path)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

How i pass the right path folder for images inside a javascript file?

For a better example:

In my main.js i have:

```
$(".background").css({background : url("../img/background.jpg") });
```

I tried to access the img path, but, this line of code **returns me a error** in console:
*"Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined"*

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".background").css({background : "url(../img/background.jpg)" });
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Right in the soul. Thank you dude. 
Another mistake i made: Delete the ../ and it will work like a charm.